# Eclipse will not compile

Tags: eclipse, compilation

So. I'm currently writing this code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHxtKDENDdE&list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28&index=30

Here is the code. This is identical to that in the Youtube video:

```
import java.util.Random;

class ArrayElementsasCounters {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Random rand = new Random();
        int freq[] = new int[7];

        for(int roll=1;roll<1000;roll++) {              
            ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];                              
        }

        System.out.println("Face\tFrequency");

        for(int face=1;face<freq.length;face++); {
            System.out.println(face+"\t"+freq[face]);
        }           
        }               
    }
```

I get this compile error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     face cannot be resolved to a variable   face cannot be
>   resolved to a variable
>
> at ArrayElementsasCounters.main(ArrayElementsasCounters.java:22)
>
> Line 22 is: **System.out.println(face+"\t"+freq[face]);**

This is working perfectly for the guy in the Youtube video, but not for me. Why?

Comment: Code works fine for me.

Comment: Really? I have tried it in Eclipse, on teamtreehouse's compiler, and at two different online compilers. Get the same error everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semi colon after for statement..

```
for(int face=1;face<freq.length;face++);
```

Remove this semicolon in your code..

Comment: Jesus ****ing christ! I have been trying to solve this for like two hours now!!

Comment: Yes. I removed it. It worked like a charm! I think I need to get some sleep. xD

Comment: Thank you for your help.